# Issue with creating a view in a tilemap environment (SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm experiencing a problem with my simple 2-dimensional tile map game. I have a character on screen that moves in all directions in a world made up of tiles/blocks. Basically I have created an array that with numbers are supposed to represent different type of blocks that in turn represent ground, sky and clouds. It helps when creating the map.

This array is for context:

```
int map[10][30] =
{
    {2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2},
    {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2},
    {2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2},
    {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
};
```

Esentially what I want to do is that I want to move all blocks in the opposite direction of where the player is walking so that a view is created. Now I don't want to use the prebuilt-in view functionality, I want to program my own view, which has led me to some problems.

I've tried with this code as an example to see if my idea would work:

```
for (int mapY = 0; mapY < 10; mapY++)
    {
        for (int mapX = 0; mapX < 30; mapX++)
        {
            if (map[mapY][mapX] == 1)
            {
                ground.setPosition(mapX * 50, mapY * 50);
                ground.move(-300, 0);
                window.draw(ground);
            }
            else if (map[mapY][mapX] == 2)
            {
                sky.setPosition(mapX * 50, mapY * 50);
                sky.move(-300, 0);
                window.draw(sky);
            }
            else if (map[mapY][mapX] == 3)
            {
                cloud.setPosition(mapX * 50, mapY * 50);
                cloud.move(-300, 0);
                window.draw(cloud);
            }
        }
    }
```

The objects in the code sky, ground, and cloud are RectangleShapes with the size 50 by 50 differentiated by different colors.

This code works for printing out the world, but for some reason i'm not moving the blocks at all. According to my logic this code would besides printing out the world also move it (all the blocks that is) for every frame. If I can make this work, I could replace the current move vector that only moves the world in one single direction, with a view_direction vector that changes depending on the state of the character (still, moving left, moving right, moviung up, moving down). Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong here or who has a better more efficient and easier idea of how to create your own view that would work in this environment.

Comment: You set the position, then move it by (-300, 0). Next iteration of the loop you again do the same thing. Set the position, then move it. This will put the block in the exact same location every time. Why do you expect it to move every frame?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php) carefully. `setPosition` "completely overwrites the previous position," while `move` "adds to the current position of the object, unlike `setPosition` which overwrites it." If you want all the tiles to move as one, frame-after-frame, then you could replace the constants `-300, 0` with some variable (like, say, `Vector2f view_offset`) that you update each frame.